# How to create an indicator function based on existence of past occurrences?

Tags: r, dplyr, panel-data

I have a time-series panel dataset that is structured in the following way: There are multiple funds that each own multiple stocks and we have a value column for the stock. As you can see the panel is not balanced. My actual dataset is very large with each fund having at least 500 stocks and different quarters being represented with some having missing quarter values.

```
df <- data.frame(
  fund_id = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2),
  stock_id = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,3,3,3,3),
  year_q = c("2011-03","2011-06","2011-09","2011-12","2012-03","2012-06","2011-12","2012-03","2012-06","2012-09",
           "2012-12","2013-03","2013-06","2014-09","2015-03","2013-03","2013-06","2013-09","2013-12"),
  value = c(1,2,1,3,4,2,1,2,3,4,2,1,3,1,1,3,2,3,1)
)


> df
   fund_id stock_id  year_q value
1        1        1 2011-03     1
2        1        1 2011-06     2
3        1        1 2011-09     1
4        1        1 2011-12     3
5        1        1 2012-03     4
6        1        1 2012-06     2
7        1        2 2011-12     1
8        1        2 2012-03     2
9        1        2 2012-06     3
10       1        2 2012-09     4
11       1        2 2012-12     2
12       1        2 2013-03     1
13       1        2 2013-06     3
14       2        1 2014-09     1
15       2        1 2015-03     1
16       2        3 2013-03     3
17       2        3 2013-06     2
18       2        3 2013-09     3
19       2        3 2013-12     1
```

I would like to create an indicator function that puts a True value if a stock was present in that quarter or any of the past 3 quarters within that fund.
Here is the result that I'm looking for:

```
result <- data.frame(
  fund_id = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
  year_q = c("2011-03","2011-06","2011-09","2011-12","2012-03","2012-06","2012-09","2012-12","2013-03","2013-06",
             "2011-03","2011-06","2011-09","2011-12","2012-03","2012-06","2012-09","2012-12","2013-03","2013-06",
             "2013-03","2013-06","2013-09","2013-12","2014-03","2014-06","2014-09","2014-12","2015-03","2013-03",
             "2013-06","2013-09","2013-12","2014-03","2014-06","2014-09","2014-12","2015-03"),
  stock_id = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3),
  Indicator = c(T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,F,F,F,F,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,F,F,F,F,F,F,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,F,F)
)

   fund_id  year_q stock_id Indicator
1        1 2011-03        1      TRUE
2        1 2011-06        1      TRUE
3        1 2011-09        1      TRUE
4        1 2011-12        1      TRUE
5        1 2012-03        1      TRUE
6        1 2012-06        1      TRUE
7        1 2012-09        1      TRUE
8        1 2012-12        1      TRUE
9        1 2013-03        1      TRUE
10       1 2013-06        1     FALSE
11       1 2011-03        2     FALSE
12       1 2011-06        2     FALSE
13       1 2011-09        2     FALSE
14       1 2011-12        2      TRUE
15       1 2012-03        2      TRUE
16       1 2012-06        2      TRUE
17       1 2012-09        2      TRUE
18       1 2012-12        2      TRUE
19       1 2013-03        2      TRUE
20       1 2013-06        2      TRUE
21       2 2013-03        1     FALSE
22       2 2013-06        1     FALSE
23       2 2013-09        1     FALSE
24       2 2013-12        1     FALSE
25       2 2014-03        1     FALSE
26       2 2014-06        1     FALSE
27       2 2014-09        1      TRUE
28       2 2014-12        1      TRUE
29       2 2015-03        1      TRUE
30       2 2013-03        3      TRUE
31       2 2013-06        3      TRUE
32       2 2013-09        3      TRUE
33       2 2013-12        3      TRUE
34       2 2014-03        3      TRUE
35       2 2014-06        3      TRUE
36       2 2014-09        3      TRUE
37       2 2014-12        3     FALSE
38       2 2015-03        3     FALSE
```

Please note that in some cases the quarters are not successive and there might be a missing quarter. (if this is too difficult to deal with you can also ignore this condition)

Additionally, I would also like to create a value zero for a quarter if the stock that was present in any of the previous 3 quarters, no longer exists in that fund. (this is not that important though).
I've been trying multiple loop solutions but since the data is massive it doesn't work that well. My ideal solution would be something using dplyr or datatable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll demonstrate using `zoo::rollapplyr` for the "this and previous 3 quarters" (4-wide window) in a `dplyr` pipe. We first need to "fill out" the quarters, which I'll do by summarizing, converting to `Date`, then `seq`uence by 3 months, merge back in to `df`, and then roll the calcs.

Note, compared to your `result`, in some cases my "forecasting" goes further into the future. I don't know if this is an inconsistency or just an indication of you estimating what you wanted `result` to look like.

Up front, the full code and results, then I'll walk through it.

```r
library(dplyr)
# library(purrr) # map2
# library(tidyr) # unnest
out <- df %>%
  group_by(fund_id) %>%
  mutate(miny = min(year_q), maxy = max(year_q)) %>%
  distinct(fund_id, stock_id, miny, maxy) %>%
  group_by(fund_id, stock_id) %>%
  mutate(across(c(miny, maxy), ~ as.Date(paste0(., "-01")))) %>%
  transmute(year_q = purrr::map2(miny, maxy, ~ format(seq(.x, .y, by = "3 months"), format = "%Y-%m")))  %>%
  tidyr::unnest(year_q) %>%
  full_join(df, by = c("fund_id", "stock_id", "year_q")) %>%
  arrange(fund_id, stock_id, year_q) %>% # only 'year_q' is strictly required, other 2 are aesthetic
  mutate(
    Indicator2 = zoo::rollapplyr(value, 4, FUN = function(z) any(!is.na(z)), partial = TRUE)
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(value = coalesce(value, 0))

out
# # A tibble: 38 x 5
#    fund_id stock_id year_q  value Indicator2
#      <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <lgl>     
#  1       1        1 2011-03     1 TRUE      
#  2       1        1 2011-06     2 TRUE      
#  3       1        1 2011-09     1 TRUE      
#  4       1        1 2011-12     3 TRUE      
#  5       1        1 2012-03     4 TRUE      
#  6       1        1 2012-06     2 TRUE      
#  7       1        1 2012-09     0 TRUE      
#  8       1        1 2012-12     0 TRUE      
#  9       1        1 2013-03     0 TRUE      
# 10       1        1 2013-06     0 FALSE     
# # ... with 28 more rows
```

Quick validation, works conveniently because the order is the same:

```r
with(full_join(out, result, by = c("fund_id", "stock_id", "year_q")),
     identical(Indicator, Indicator2))
# [1] TRUE
```

Walk-through:

1. Find the min/max `year_q` for each `fund_id`:

   ```r
   df %>%
     group_by(fund_id) %>%
     mutate(miny = min(year_q), maxy = max(year_q)) %>%
     distinct(fund_id, stock_id, miny, maxy)
   # # A tibble: 4 x 4
   # # Groups:   fund_id [2]
   #   fund_id stock_id miny    maxy   
   #     <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>   <chr>  
   # 1       1        1 2011-03 2013-06
   # 2       1        2 2011-03 2013-06
   # 3       2        1 2013-03 2015-03
   # 4       2        3 2013-03 2015-03
   ```
2. "Fill" that out so that each `stock_id` is covered for the full time-frame of the `fund_id`:

   ```r
   ... %>%
     group_by(fund_id, stock_id) %>%
     mutate(across(c(miny, maxy), ~ as.Date(paste0(., "-01")))) %>%
     transmute(year_q = purrr::map2(miny, maxy, ~ format(seq(.x, .y, by = "3 months"), format = "%Y-%m")))  %>%
     tidyr::unnest(year_q)
   # # A tibble: 38 x 3
   # # Groups:   fund_id, stock_id [4]
   #    fund_id stock_id year_q 
   #      <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>  
   #  1       1        1 2011-03
   #  2       1        1 2011-06
   #  3       1        1 2011-09
   #  4       1        1 2011-12
   #  5       1        1 2012-03
   #  6       1        1 2012-06
   #  7       1        1 2012-09
   #  8       1        1 2012-12
   #  9       1        1 2013-03
   # 10       1        1 2013-06
   # # ... with 28 more rows
   ```
3. Join the original data back in. This shows us quarters that were missing.

   ```r
   ... %>%
     full_join(df, by = c("fund_id", "stock_id", "year_q")) %>%
     arrange(fund_id, stock_id, year_q)
   # # A tibble: 38 x 4
   # # Groups:   fund_id, stock_id [4]
   #    fund_id stock_id year_q  value
   #      <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
   #  1       1        1 2011-03     1
   #  2       1        1 2011-06     2
   #  3       1        1 2011-09     1
   #  4       1        1 2011-12     3
   #  5       1        1 2012-03     4
   #  6       1        1 2012-06     2
   #  7       1        1 2012-09    NA
   #  8       1        1 2012-12    NA
   #  9       1        1 2013-03    NA
   # 10       1        1 2013-06    NA
   # # ... with 28 more rows
   ```
4. Perform the "rolling" calculation. This is the majority of "work": for each `value`, we look at it and the previous 3 values (4 minus 1 for the current gives us 3 previous values) and determine if any are non-`NA`. `partial=TRUE` means that for the first `value` (that has no previous), we look at it alone; for the second `value`, we look at it and the 1 previous; etc. With `partial=TRUE`, this returns the same length as `value`; if `partial=FALSE` (the default), then it would return `length(value) - (4-1)` values, which is not what we want.

   ```r
   ... %>%
     # only 'year_q' is strictly required, other 2 are aesthetic
     mutate(
       Indicator2 = zoo::rollapplyr(value, 4, FUN = function(z) any(!is.na(z)), partial = TRUE)
     )
   # # A tibble: 38 x 5
   # # Groups:   fund_id, stock_id [4]
   #    fund_id stock_id year_q  value Indicator2
   #      <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <lgl>     
   #  1       1        1 2011-03     1 TRUE      
   #  2       1        1 2011-06     2 TRUE      
   #  3       1        1 2011-09     1 TRUE      
   #  4       1        1 2011-12     3 TRUE      
   #  5       1        1 2012-03     4 TRUE      
   #  6       1        1 2012-06     2 TRUE      
   #  7       1        1 2012-09    NA TRUE      
   #  8       1        1 2012-12    NA TRUE      
   #  9       1        1 2013-03    NA TRUE      
   # 10       1        1 2013-06    NA FALSE     
   # # ... with 28 more rows
   ```
5. Finally, arrange (for convenience only) and convert all `is.na(value)` to `0`.

---

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(df)
year_qs <- distinct(
  DT[, c("miny", "maxy") := .(min(year_q), max(year_q)), by = .(fund_id)
     ][, .(fund_id, stock_id, miny, maxy)]
)[, c("miny","maxy") := lapply(.SD, function(z) as.Date(paste0(z, "-01"))), .SDcols = c("miny","maxy")
  ][, .(year_q = Map(function(a, b) format(seq.Date(a, b, by = "3 months"), format = "%Y-%m"), miny, maxy)),
    by = .(fund_id, stock_id)
    ][, tidyr::unnest(.SD, year_q) ]
setDT(year_qs)
DT[, c("miny", "maxy") := NULL]

DT <- rbindlist(list(
  DT,
  year_qs[!DT, on = .(fund_id, stock_id, year_q)]),
  use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
setorder(DT, fund_id, stock_id, year_q)

DT[, Indicator := zoo::rollapplyr(value, 4, FUN = function(z) any(!is.na(z)), partial = TRUE),
   by = .(fund_id, stock_id)
   ][, value := fcoalesce(value, 0)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution! Can't express how grateful I am. I'm currently running the modified version on my full sample of more than 100 million data points hopefully the code would be efficient enough to run in less than a day.

Comment: Ahh, 100 million ... depending on your runtime, you may prefer a `data.table` solution ... lmk how the performance fairs ...

Comment: Yeah, I usually only use data.table with this project. It seems like it would take way too long to run this for my data size. Would you be kind enough to suggest a data.table solution? I would be really grateful.

Comment: Take a look at the edit. It's not beautiful. The `rbindlist` may be a little costly, since it's effectively going to duplicate your data in memory. (I don't think that's avoidable, since "adding rows" programmatically at the user-level is not something `data.table` is doing in-place, iirc.

Comment: Thank you very much r2evans. I really really appreciate your help.

Comment: After running the code I'm dealing with a problem. Since we are assigning zero to all the NA columns whereas I only want 0 to be assigned the first time a stock vanishes from the fund portfolio in the next period. So let's say fund 1 had stock 1 in time 1 and in time 2 that stock is no longer there then I would like to have zero weight for that stock but just for that next quarter. I can't properly count the proportions of TRUE to FALSE. My objective is to find what percentage of the stocks stayed the same in each quarter compared within the past 1-12 quarters tbc...

Comment: Continued from the above: so if that stock was ever held in any of 1-12 past quarters then we consider it TRUE if not then its false (that's why we need that initial zero weight after some stock vanishes as we still want it to count in only the next quarter).